# Алгоритм с выводом и вводом работают некорректно(неправильно кодирует)

Tags: c++, utf-8

Пытался убирать, устанавливать локали, ипользовал разные методы, и ничего не работает.
вот код с комментариями:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<array>

std::array<std::wstring, std::size_t(4)> list = {
    L"ютуб.ру",
    L"твиттер.ру",
    L"вк.ру",
    L"вконтакте.ру",
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //ввод информации в entered_info
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    std::wstring entered_info;
    std::getline(std::wcin, entered_info);

    std::wcout << L"entered_info[0]: " <<entered_info[0] << std::endl; //здесь неправильно выводит

    //сортировка и подбор подходящего результата
    int index = 0;
    std::wstring found = L"неизвестно";
    std::size_t max_last_coincidence = 0;
    std::size_t max_coincidence = 0;

    while (index < list.max_size())
    {
        for (int symbol = 0; std::size_t(symbol) != list[index].max_size(); symbol++)
        {
            std::wcout << list[index][symbol] << std::endl;
            if (entered_info[symbol] == list[index][symbol]) // условие ложно из-за выше сказанного
            {
                max_coincidence++;
            }
            else {
                break;
            };
        };
        if (max_last_coincidence < max_coincidence)
        {
            found = list[index];
            max_last_coincidence = max_coincidence;
        };
        max_coincidence = 0;
        index++;
    };
    std::wcout << found << std::endl; // в итоге, выводит ВСЕГДА "неизвестно"

    //ожидание, чтобы не закрылось и виден был результат
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
};
```

я использую:

```
компилятор: g++
операционная система: windows 11
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [imbue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue): `std::wcout.imbue(std::locale("C.UTF-8"));`, `std::wcin.imbue(std::locale("C.UTF-8"));`

Comment: попробовал, не сработало

Comment: непонятно: что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, проблема в выводе на консоль или в алгоритме? Советую ознакомиться с концепцией [mcve]